# order of $x^m$ given the order of group element $x$ is $n$, where $\gcd(m,n)=d$, revisited question

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

The following is an exercise from "Guide to Abstract Algebra", 1st edition, Carol Whitehead.

> Let $G$ be a group and $x \in G$. Suppose $o(x)= n$ and $m$ is an
> integer such that $\gcd(m, n) = d$. Prove that $o(x^m) = n/d$.

Here $o(x)$ is the order of the element $x$, the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $x^r = e$, the identity element.

I previously posted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694005/order-of-xm-given-the-order-of-group-element-x-is-n-where-gcdm-n-d) but the replies were not able to help me (my fault, not theirs).

**Question:** I have made another attempt at a solution, but unsure if it is correct.

---

**My Attempted Solution:**

We start with what the order of an element $x$ means,

$$o(x) = n \implies x^n = e$$

So,

$$  e = x^n = (x^2)^{n/2} = (x^3)^{n/3} = \ldots  = (x^m)^{n/m}$$

These exponents $n/m$ are the smallest they can be, because $n$ is already the smallest for $m=1$. To illustrate, $(x^2)^{100 n/2} = e$, but the exponent is 100 times larger than it could be.

However, the exponent $n/m$ is not necessarily an integer. So our task is to find the smallest multiple of $n/m$ which is an integer.

We need to find the smallest $k$ such that $(n/m)k$ that is an integer.

If we think about the unique prime factorisation of $m$ and $n$, then $k$ needs to contain those prime factors of $m$ that are not in $n$. That is $k=m/d$.

This then gives us

$$ e=(x^m)^{kn/m} = (x^m)^{n/d} $$

So $o(x^m) = n/d$.

Comment: This question has been asked many times here.  The duplicate I linked to is itself a duplicate.  Of another duplicate.

Comment: hi @Lulu this group $G$ is not defined to be cyclic.

Comment: I am just hoping for some sympathetic expert to say "yes that is correct" or "no, and this is why" - is that too much to hope for on math.stack?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The group generate by $x$ is, by definition, cyclic.

Comment: hi @Lulu - I'm not an expert and find the explanation on your linked duplicates difficult to understand. I would really appreciate anyone who can answer this specific solution as it is written in terms I can understand.

Comment: You have asked here yesterday. Please show your effort before posting another question. [order of $x^m$ given the order of group element $x$ is $n$, where $\gcd(m,n)=d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694005/order-of-xm-given-the-order-of-group-element-x-is-n-where-gcdm-n-d)

Comment: For a general remark, your proof is too vague.  You have to actually prove that the order is that smallest multiple, not just assert it.  Study the many, many proofs of this standard remark.  The solutions to [this version of the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906718/how-to-prove-ak-n-gcdn-k-whenever-a-n) follow similar lines to what you want.

Comment: hi @Lulu The thrust of the argument given is indeed to show the order is the smallest multiple. The first sentence even illustrates a counter example.  The consideration of prime factors, or the formula for LCD in other answers, does the same thing - find the smallest multiple. Am I wrong?